# CakePHP Array Merge for CSV Data Mapping

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an application that reads in a CSV file (using CakeDC CsvImportBehavior), than presents a screen for a user to map the fields found in the CSV File to Database tables. This all works fine. I've created a view that presents the Database Models form fields, with select boxes to choose the CSV row to associate with that model row. When saved have 3 arrays:

1. Array of field mappings:

   ```
   array(
   'Map' => array(
       'name' => '0',
       'address' => '5',
       'city' => '6',
       'use_city' => '1',
       'state' => '7',
       'use_state' => '1',
       'zip' => '8',
       'use_zip' => '1',
       'details' => '12'
   )
   ```

   )
2. Array of CSV Headers

   ```
   array(
   (int) 0 => 'Name',
   (int) 1 => 'Email',
   (int) 2 => 'HR',
   (int) 3 => 'HR Email',
   (int) 4 => 'Company',
   (int) 5 => 'Address',
   (int) 6 => 'City',
   (int) 7 => 'State',
   (int) 8 => 'Zip',
   (int) 9 => 'Phone',
   (int) 10 => 'Number',
   (int) 11 => 'Frequency',
   (int) 12 => 'Details',
   (int) 13 => 'Date Signed'
   ```

   )
3. Array of models with CSV Headers as properties (this is the one that needs to be modified)

   ```
   array(
   (int) 0 => array(
       'Marker' => array(
       'Name' => 'Randy Watson',
       'Email' => ' @SBCGlobal.net',
       'HR' => 'Randy Watson',
       'HR_Email' => 'bogusjunk@sbcglobal.net',
       'Company' => 'Secure Financial, Inc.',
       'Address' => '2865 Sombrero Circle',
       'City' => 'San Ramon',
       'State' => 'CA',
       'Zip' => '94583',
       'Phone' => '925-973-1088',
       'Number' => '6',
       'Frequency' => '$60',
       'Details' => '',
       'Date_Signed' => 'Mar 6, 11:10 2011'
       )
   ),
   ```

   ...

So basically I have to make array #3's keys represent the selections made in array #1 so that they match up and are save-able via model->save() ... Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: my guess: 2 for-each loops and you'll be done with it.

Comment: That's what i was thinking, I was just thinking there's a way to utilize one of the PHP functions i.e. array_merge...etc...started trying to foreach though, may just need to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, perhaps this is of any help:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html